# Аналог @import в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, flask

**Вопрос** Как нужно подгружать все задействованные библиотеки JavaScript из одного файла, как это есть в CSS?

В CSS с недавних пор появился `@import`, который позволяет контролировать подгруздку стилей из одного файла, что очень удобно.

У конечного продукта нет доступа в сеть, поэтому нужные зависимости собираются вместе.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- остальные преформы -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Структура проекта довольно простая:

```
.
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   ├── datatables.min.css
│   │   └── main.css
│   ├── font
│   ├── img
│   └── js
│       └── main.js
└── templates
```

*static/css/main.css*

```
@import 'bootstrap.min.css'
@import 'datatables.min.css'

/* подгонка стилей под проект */
```

**Ссылки**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Comment: `В CSS с недавних пор появился @import` - С не давних пор? Хах, серьезно? Да это еще появилось лет 15 назад. И это лучше не использовать. А про импорт `js`, пробегайтесь по файлам, создавайте компресс и отдавайте его через заголовки, в чем проблема?

Comment: @And  Проблем нет, есть необходимость держать библиотеки в явно указанных файлах. Про  не использование  \@import  не нашел ни каких "противопоказаний"

Comment: Не совсем понятно цель данной манипуляции. В JS как таковом нет такого функционала, но можно написать свой скрипт с подгрузкой файла из JS в другой JS. Точно не имеется ввиду JS фреймворки + компонентный подход???

Comment: Вообще-то есть https://learn.javascript.ru/modules-intro

Comment: В вашем случае будет лучше просто создать из всех файлов 1, сделать компрессию (сжатие) и отдавать как статичный файл, если нужна динамика - `php` внедрить или еще что-то, то тогда собирайте файл на сервере и отдавайте уже собранный. В ином случае:   Есть `import`, но он не так давно появился, тоже вариант, Уже в целом использовать за место Нативных методов, использовать Классы и Модули.

Answer (score 0):

## Импорт всех umd библиотек в одном js файле.

> ### css
>
> ```
>   @import 'bootstrap.min.css'
>   @import 'datatables.min.css'
> ```

### js

```
// umdLibLoader.js
import './A.js'
import './B.js'
```

### демо.

```html
<script type="module"> // umdLibLoader.js
  import 'https://unpkg.com/jquery'
  import 'https://unpkg.com/underscore'
  import 'https://unpkg.com/backbone'
  import 'https://unpkg.com/d3'

  // import './index.js'
</script>

<script type="module"> // index.js
  [
    '$', '_', 'Backbone', 'd3',
  ].forEach(q => console.log(!!window[q], q));
</script>
```